# Counting number of zeros in a row, adding count to new column

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have a tab-delimited table that looks like this:

```
chr1 100 110 + 2 3 0 8 6
chr1 150 200 + 1 4 0 2 0
chr1 200 220 + 1 4 2 0 0
chr1 250 260 + 4 2 6 1 3
```

I would like to count how many zeros are in columns 5-9 and add that number to column 10:

```
chr1 100 110 + 2 3 0 8 6 1
chr1 150 200 + 1 4 0 2 0 2
chr1 200 220 + 1 4 2 0 0 2
chr1 250 260 + 4 2 6 1 3 0
```

Ultimately, the goal is to subset only those rows with no more than 4 zeros (at least 2 columns being non-zero). I know how to do this subset with `awk` but I don't know how to count the zeros in those columns. If there is a simpler way to just require that at least two columns be non-zero between columns 5-9 that would be ideal.

Comment: You want to select rows having two zeros or add a new column with the zero count?

Comment: Rather than posting some output and then saying `Ultimately, the goal...` and describing something different you'd like to do instead, just state what the ultimate goal is and provide the expected output given that goal. Also add your code to show you've tried to solve the problem yourself before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rethab's answer perfectly answers your first requirement of adding an extra column. This answers your second requirement (print only lines with less than 4 zeros). With awk (tested with GNU awk), simply count the non-zero fields between field 5 et field 9 (variable `nz`), and print only if it is greater or equal 2:

```sh
$ cat foo.txt
chr1 100 110 + 2 3 0 8 6
chr1 150 200 + 1 4 0 2 0
chr1 250 260 + 0 0 0 1 0
chr1 200 220 + 1 4 2 0 0
chr1 250 260 + 4 2 6 1 3
$ awk '{nz=0; for(i=5;i<=9;i++) nz+=($i!=0)} nz>=2' foo.txt
chr1 100 110 + 2 3 0 8 6
chr1 150 200 + 1 4 0 2 0
chr1 200 220 + 1 4 2 0 0
chr1 250 260 + 4 2 6 1 3
```

Answer (score 2):

This script counts the zeros and appends them as the last column:

```sh
awk '{
  cnt=0
  for (i=5;i<=9;i++) {
    cnt+=($i==0)
  }
  print $0, cnt
}' inputs.txt
```

note that `$i==0` yields 1 if the condition is true and 0 if not. Therefore, this can be used as the increment for the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub` which returns the number of sustitutions per line (here per `s` string) and then print the number:

```
awk '{s=$5$6$7$8$9;x=gsub(/0/,"&",s);print $0, x}' file
chr1 100 110 + 2 3 0 8 6 1
chr1 150 200 + 1 4 0 2 0 2
chr1 200 220 + 1 4 2 0 0 2
chr1 250 260 + 4 2 6 1 3 0
```

Comment: this will fail with numbers like 10 and alike.

Comment: Here `to count how many zeros are in columns 5-9` is the question.